# Functional code examples in ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, rubygems

I'm looking for examples of functional code in ruby. Maybe you know some gems, where I can find such a code?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "functional"? There are two very different definitions of that term in wide use: programming with higher-order procedures and programming without side-effects. It is almost impossible to write Ruby *without* using higher-order procedures, so if you use the first definition, then your answer is that pretty much all Ruby code is functional. OTOH, it is almost impossible to write code without side-effects, so if you use the second definition, then the answer is that almost no Ruby code is functional.

Comment: @Jörg: Which side-effects does banister's code snippet have?

Comment: @sepp2k: I have no idea. And that's exactly the problem. I have no idea whether `select`, `%`, `==`, `map`, `*` or `take` have side-effects or not. But if even *one* of them has even a single side-effect, then the entire piece of code is not functional according to the second definition. Side-effects are contageous. That's why it is so hard to write side-effect-free code in Ruby: you cannot call *any* method that you haven't written yourself.

Comment: @jorg: there are degrees of "functional". even though it doesn't include a monad system, I would say bannisters answer is probably the thing I would be looking for if I asked that question, not a description of why ruby isn't haskell.

Comment: @Matt Briggs: I only know of one functional language that includes a monad system out of the box, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Answer (score 7):

I've been gathering examples of functional programming with Ruby:

- [Wiki page](https://github.com/tokland/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)
- Presentation: [Functional programming with Ruby](http://www.slideshare.net/tokland/functional-programming-with-ruby-9975242).

Comment: Awesome! Note that just this week there was a proposal on the ruby-core mailinglist for `Enumerable#lazy` (which is similar to Scala's `view` method if you are familiar with that), which returns a lazy "view" of the underlying collection and provides lazy implementations of Ruby's `Enumerable` protocols. So, e.g. calling `an_enumerator.lazy.map { ... }` will not result in an infinite loop even if the `Enumerator` is infinite.

Comment: @Jörg: thanks for the reference I don't follow the mailing-list (I should...). The Facets project (when you think you have found some new and original abstraction, those guys made it years ago!) use this same "lazy" proxy, they call it "defer": require 'facets'; (1..1.0/0).defer.select { |x| x % 2 }.map { |x| 2*x }.take(5).to_a #=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]. It would be very nice that vanilla Ruby go in this direction (IMO operations on enumerators should return enumerators, never arrays), the support for laziness is still poor.

Comment: I think that *all* collection operations should be type-preserving. I.e. operations on a `Set` should return a `Set`, an `Enumerator` should return an `Enumerator` and so on. The way it is done in Ruby or .NET, where all operations return the same type, regardless of what you started with, is really annoying. At least in .NET, you get a very general, abstract, potentially lazy interface type (`IEnumerable`), but in Ruby you always get a concrete, eager, fully realized `Array`. Scala gets this right. (Scala's collections framework is hands down the best. Smalltalk, STL, Ruby aren't even close.)

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Enumerable?

```
(1..100).select { |i| i % 5 == 0 }.map { |i| i * 5 }.take(3) #=> [25, 50, 75]
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of months ago, I wondered whether it was possible to make a mixin that behaves *exactly* like `Enumerable`, but is based on *folding* instead of *enumerating*. Or more precisely, I already *knew* that it was possible to do this, since *fold* is a generic iteration operation that is equal in expressive power to *foreach*, but I wanted to know what it would look like and how hard it would be.

I got bored after I had implemented most methods up to the letter *g*, so it's incomplete. Also, the version I show here is simplified, since making it behave *exactly* like `Enumerable` is a PITA in Ruby. (For example, there are overloaded methods in there, but Ruby doesn't support overloading. This isn't a problem for most Ruby implementations, because they implement `Enumerable` in Java or C# or other languages that *do* support overloading, but it is pretty painful when doing it in pure Ruby, so I decided to leave it out.)

`Enumerable` is full of higher-order procedures, and of course *fold* (or `reduce` / `inject` as it is called in Ruby) is *itself* a higher-order procedure, so this code is full of them.

```
module Enumerable
  def all?
    reduce(true) {|res, el| res && yield(el) }
  end

  def any?
    reduce(false) {|res, el| res || yield(el) }
  end

  def collect
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res + yield(el) }
  end
  alias_method :map, :collect

  def count
    reduce(0) {|res, el| res + 1 if yield el }
  end

  def detect
    reduce(nil) {|res, el| if yield el then el end unless res }
  end
  alias_method :find, :detect

  def drop(n=1)
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res + el unless n -= 1 >= 0 }}
  end

  def each
    reduce(nil) {|_, el| yield el }
  end

  def each_with_index
    reduce(-1) {|i, el| (i+1).tap {|i| yield el, i }}
  end

  def find_all
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res + el if yield el }}
  end
  alias_method :select, :find_all

  def grep(pattern)
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res + yield(el) if pattern === el }}
  end

  def group_by
    reduce(Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }) {|res, el| res.tap {|res|
        res[yield el] << el
    }}
  end

  def include?(obj)
    reduce(false) {|res, el| break true if res || el == obj }
  end

  def reject
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res + el unless yield el }}
  end
end
```

You will notice that I use side-effects in some places. I could have written it without side-effects instead, but it would have been much more complicated. And the problem is that there is no way for me to ensure that the `reduce` method, which is provided by the *client* of the mixin, or any of the methods from the core library, don't have side-effects.

Another nice example is the [Prelude](http://AppDesign.Com/products/open-source-projects/prelude-library/) library for Ruby, which is an implementation of some parts of the Haskell Prelude (Haskell's equivalent to Ruby's core library) in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the talk "Better Ruby through Functional Programming" by Dean Wampler, it shows how to use a FP style with Ruby:

http://vimeo.com/6701329

There's also "Thinking functionally in Ruby" by Tom Stuart:

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/ajax-ria/enumerators

Comment: Second link is a purely for-pay ebook link.

Comment: The second link is a video presentation about FP in Ruby: "During our last meeting, Tom was surprised by how many people (both Ruby newbies and "Rails not Ruby" programmers) were asking questions about Enumerable, e.g. what map/inject/zip etc do."

Answer (score 1):

"The Ruby Programming Language" has half a chapter where they work on a couple of additions to enumerable to make ruby look like Haskell.

You may also want to browse previous Stack Overflow questions tagged with both "Ruby" and "functional-programming" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming%2bruby).

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty or efficient code. It is to explain the difference between a functional and non functional style.

Something you need to think about when doing functional concepts in ruby is that our vm is not built for it, so without transparent referential optimization, you WILL eat a lot more memory writing in a functional style.

```
# non functional
class Post
  attr_accessor :title, :body
end

all_posts = []

# create a post
p = Post.new
p.title = "Hello world"
p.body  = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

# put post in the array
all_posts << p

# fix post title
all_posts[0].title = "Opps, fixed title"

#functional
class Post
  attr_reader :title, :body

  def initialize(attrs={})
    attrs.each {|k,v| instance_variable_set "@#{k.to_s}", v }
  end
end

all_posts = []

# create a post
p = Post.new({title: "Hello world", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."})
# add to array via new array creation
all_posts = all_posts + [p] # be wary when all_posts is a very large collection!

old_post = p
p = Post.new({title: "Oops, fixed title", body: old_post.body})
all_posts = all_posts - [old_post] + [p]
```

I post on functional programming in ruby quite often at my blog: http://rubylove.io