# Re-writing a "better" code

Tags: ruby, arrays, coding-style, initialization

I am using Ruby 1.9 and I would like to know if there is a "better" way to write the following code.

```
  array_one = []
  array_two = []
  some_array.each { |value|
    array_one << value.id
    array_two << value.name
  }
```

I "don't like" to initialize `array_one` and `array_two` like in the above example and then add in those `value.id` and `value.name`. *This because and mostly for a better understanding and reading of the code in my application.*

I would like to provide the same functionality but with a "better" coding. Is it possible?

Comment: I think it's good enough. We usually use the do end form for blocks having more than one instruction, but, other than that, explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code pattern you have there, is usually a sure sign of a `fold` (or more generally a *catamorphism*) wanting to get out. Ruby does provide a built-in method for folding, for historical reasons it is called `inject`.

Untested:

```
array_one, array_two = some_array.
  inject([[], []]) {|(array_one, array_two), value|
    [array_one << value.id, array_two << value.name]
}
```

Not sure whether you think this is "better" or not. For someone who understands what a `fold` is, this is probably clearer. For someone who doesn't, it's probably not.

(Although I think that if you *don't* understand what a `fold` is, then you are not a very good Ruby programmer, or even a very good programmer *at all*, but that is just my opinion.)

However, saying that some iteration is a `fold` isn't really terribly useful, since `fold` is a general method of iteration (which means that *every* form of iteration can be expressed as a `fold`). What you *really* have here, is a `map`:

```
array_one, array_two = some_array.map(&:id), some_array.map(&:value)
```

Note that this will traverse `some_array` twice. However, unless you have credible benchmarks and profiling results that show that this double traversal is a major source of performance troubles in your application, you really shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: BTW: Where I can find some information to understand 'fold' (other than http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)?

Comment: Why are you using `inject` rather than `each_with_object`?

Comment: Although most books on Ruby talk about blocks, I don't think many Ruby books explicitly talk about functional programming (in either the higher level functions or immutable object sense) at length.

Comment: @user502052: Although I wish the answers to the following question were better, try perusing the link from tokland's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833372/functional-code-examples-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Array#collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247) method:

```
array_one = some_array.collect { |value| value.id }
array_two = some_array.collect { |value| value.name }
```

As Jörg W Mittag mentioned in his answer, this solution will also traverse the source array twice.

Comment: Like you propose it will traverse the 'some_array' twice... I think that is not good for performance.

Comment: I'm curious about why you think iterating twice is slow. I bet it's much faster than some of these answers (like inject) that create a ton of throw-away arrays as they iterate once. In a theoretical sense, you should count the number of operations, not the number of iterations. Iterating once and doing two things in each iteration is the same as iterating twice and doing only one of those things in each, except for the teeny tiny overhead of the collect, which is far smaller than allocating a bunch of arrays that need to be garbage collected. Plus, this answer is very clear.

Comment: Run `time ruby -e '10000000.times { |i| i.to_s }'` and `time ruby -e '5000000.times { |i| i.to_s }; 5000000.times { |i| i.to_s }'` a few times and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `transpose` to transform an n-element array containing two-element arrays into two n-element arrays:

```
array_one, array_two = some_array.map {|value| [value.id, value.name]}.transpose
```

Here's the [RDoc link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000261), though it's fairly terse.