# There is any objective reason why Scala differentiate fold and reduce functions?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Reduce can be an override fold that doesn't take the first element.
I guess there is an answer to that design decision but I can't find it.

Comment: To be honest `reduce` is mostly useless compared with `foldLeft` I don't think I have used it in years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two operations are fundamentally different. Giving them the same name would be confusing. In [Ruby](https://ruby-lang.org/), the equivalent method is called [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aliased to [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)) and is overloaded to act like both Scala's [`scala.collection.Iterable.foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/Iterable.html#foldLeft-fffff9e1) and [`scala.collection.Iterable.reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/Iterable.html#reduceLeft-fffff3d4). And you can see the confusion this causes in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).

[Note: From here on, I will use Scala terminology to refer to the two different operations, i.e. `fold` and `reduce`.]

Some of the differences between the two operations are:

- `fold` works with an empty collection, `reduce` doesn't. In Scala, it will either throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) or you can use [`scala.collection.Iterable.reduceLeftOption[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): Option[B]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/Iterable.html#reduceLeftOption-8fe). In [Haskell](https://haskell.org/), what Scala calls `reduceLeft` is called [`Data.List.foldl1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1) for that reason: because you need at least **1** element.
- With `reduce`, the result type is the same as the element type (or more precisely, a *supertype* of the element type), whereas with `fold`, the result type can be *anything*. For example, you cannot sum the lengths of a collection of strings with `reduce` because the result type of `reduce` on a collection of strings cannot be a number, it must be string.
- The most important one: `fold` is a *general iteration operation*, meaning, *everything you can do with a loop or with recursion, you can do with a `fold`*. If you have `fold`, you don't need `map`, you don't need `filter`, you don't need `forall`, you don't need `groupBy`, you don't need `scan`, and so on, and of course you also don't need `reduce`. You can implement all of them using `fold`. ([I did that for Ruby once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834035/2988).) `reduce` is *not* general, and you can't e.g. implement *any* collection transformation (e.g. `map` or `filter` or even just `reverse`) because the result type of `reduce` is the element type and cannot be the collection type.

Because those two operations are so different, it just makes sense to give them different names: `fold` and `reduce` in Scala, `foldX` and `foldX1` in Haskell, etc. In the language I am most familiar with, Ruby, they have the same name, and that has led to confusion.

Comment: `foldX1` really adds _so much clarity_  ... :D

Answer (score 1):

In short, they have different type constraints, and therefore different type signatures. The result of a `fold` can be anything you want. The result of a `reduce` must be a supertype of the elements.

This is why `fold` and `reduce` are usually combined in dynamically-typed languages, but separated in statically-typed languages.